# Ignore " character when using textscan() in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io, literals, textscan

I am using textscan to read data from a file.  The data being read is:

```
"ABC",0.156
"DEF",0.125
"GHI",0.101
```

My code is - `data = textscan(fid, '%s %f', 'Delimiter', ',');`

data{1} come as

```
'"ABC"'
'"DEF"'
'"GHI"'
```

I want the data{1} as -

```
'ABC'
'DEF'
'GHI'
```

Finally, how can I have the answer as

```
data = 
'ABC' [0.156];
'DEF' [0.125];
'GHI' [0.101];
```

instead of using data{1} and data{2}.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually two ways to ignore the `"` characters when reading your strings. As per the [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) documentation, you can use the `%q` format instead of the `%s` format:

```
data = textscan(fid,'%q %f','Delimiter',',');
```

Or you can read the strings using the `%s` format and remove the `"` characters from `data{1}` using the function [STRREP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strrep.html):

```
data{1} = strrep(data{1},'"','');
```

Then you can use the function [NUM2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/num2cell.html) to convert the array of numeric values in `data{2}` to a cell array so that you can [concatenate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-84864.html) it with the cell array of strings in `data{1}`:

```
>> data = [data{1} num2cell(data{2})];

data =

    'ABC'    [0.1560]
    'DEF'    [0.1250]
    'GHI'    [0.1010]
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get rid of the double quotes use

```
data = textscan(fid, '%q %f', 'Delimiter', ',');
```

where `%q` does the magic.